# Ignore specified HTML blocks in markdown-it?

Tags: html, node.js, markdown, markdown-it

I have following markdown:

```
> Acronis True Image does not allow to clone a single partition; only cloning of an entire disk is possible
> [Acronis True Image: how to clone a disk | Knowledge Base](https://kb.acronis.com/content/56634)

But you can use <a href="https://px.a8.net/svt/ejp?a8mat=3H7MDC+20NGN6+49QG+5YJRM" rel="nofollow">this</a><img border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www11.a8.net/0.gif?a8mat=3H7MDC+20NGN6+49QG+5YJRM" alt="">.
```

markdown-it renders the one to like this:

```
<blockquote>
<p>Acronis True Image does not allow to clone a single partition; only cloning of an entire disk is possible    
<a href="https://kb.acronis.com/content/56634">Acronis True Image: how to clone a disk | Knowledge Base</a></p> 
</blockquote>
<p>But you can use &lt;a href=&quot;https://px.a8.net/svt/ejp?a8mat=3H7MDC+20NGN6+49QG+5YJRM&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;this&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;1&quot; height=&quot;1&quot; src=&quot;https://www11.a8.net/0.gif?a8mat=3H7MDC+20NGN6+49QG+5YJRM&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;.</p>
```

But actually I want to render the one to something like this:

```
<blockquote>
<p>Acronis True Image does not allow to clone a single partition; only cloning of an entire disk is possible    
<a href="https://kb.acronis.com/content/56634">Acronis True Image: how to clone a disk | Knowledge Base</a></p> 
</blockquote>
<p>But you can use <a href="https://px.a8.net/svt/ejp?a8mat=3H7MDC+20NGN6+49QG+5YJRM" rel="nofollow">this</a><img border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www11.a8.net/0.gif?a8mat=3H7MDC+20NGN6+49QG+5YJRM" alt="">.</p>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `html` option:

```js
var md = require('markdown-it')({
  html: true,
});
```

As [documented](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#MarkdownIt.new), `html` is disabled by default, which explains why it is being escaped.

> options:
>
> - **html** - `false`. Set `true` to enable HTML tags in source. Be careful! That's not safe! You may need external sanitizer to protect
>   output from XSS. It's better to extend features via plugins, instead
>   of enabling HTML.

Comment: How do I do it without node.js but directly in a HTML?